# if and else in bash not working

Tags: bash, shell

I can't figure out where I am messing this up but its killing me and the more I mess with it the worse it gets.
I am trying to get a directory from user and display it before asking for a search term within the directory. I want the user to have to specifically type  "q!" to exit, or else it just starts from the beginning. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter directory name, pwd for present working directory, or q! for quit.'
read $dirName
echo $dirName
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
echo 'Enter part, or all of the filename'
read $fileName
echo $fileName
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
if [ "$dirName" = "q!"]; then
  exit 0
else
  ls -l $dirName
  ls -a *$fileName*
fi
```

Comment: i think you want $dirName eq ".."

Comment: You use `$variable` when you want the variable expanded; you use just `variable` when you want to assign to `variable` (`variable=value`, `read variable`, `while getopts "$opts" variable`, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the user to have to specifically type "q!" to exit, or else it
>   just starts from the beginning

you need to use loop, and check the user input, only break the loop when user input `"q!"`.
`$` is not needed in `read $dirName` (and the other `read` too).

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
        echo 'Enter directory name, pwd for present working directory, or q! for quit.'
        read dirName
        [ "x$dirName" == "xq!" ] && break
        #do other stuff
done
```

Comment: Not so much '`$` is not needed' as '`$1 must not be present'!

Comment: #!/bin/bash
    while true
    do
      echo 'Enter directory name, pwd for present working directory, or q! for quit.'
    read dirName
    [ $dirName == 'q!' ] && break

    echo 'Enter part, or all of the filename'
    read fileName
    ls -la -- "$fileName"*
    done

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter directory name, pwd for present working directory, or q! for quit.'
read dirName                      #<--- remove $
echo $dirName
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
echo 'Enter part, or all of the filename'
read fileName                     #<--- remove $
echo $fileName
read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."
if [ "$dirName" = "q!" ]; then    #<--- add space after "q!"
  exit 0
else
  ls -l $dirName
  ls -a *$fileName*
fi
```

This works in my pc.

Comment: I was missing that space but I still cannot get this thing to quit on "q!"